# How to make animate line with an arrow in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-animate

How to make animate line with an arrow in Adobe Animate CC like below:

[image: picture[1]]

Not necessarily dashed line. But it is necessary that the arrow would go not only along a straight trajectory but also along a drawn path.
I'm new in Adobe Animate and have not found such arrows like in Illustrator were where used arrowhead to stroke of line.

UPD
my attempts to solve the problem

attemp with  classic motion tween for mask
[image: picture[3]]

attemp with  shape motion tween for mask
[image: picture[4]]

attemp with  shape motion tween for shape mask. It `s better now, but the mask does not even cover the line that appears underneath it
[image: picture[5]]

UPD №2
shape tween for line with paint brush in the form of an arrow. 
For a straight path, it is suitable, but generally bad for the curve trajectory.

[image]

Comment: I haven't used flash for a while but I'd definitely not recommend using motion tween in this case. As you see the tip of your arrow spins out of control at the end.

Comment: @Luciano It seems that found the better option instead of the tip, but the problem with the motion in the trajectory  is present.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to animate the parts separately. Sometimes shape tween deforms the objects into undesirable shapes.

Do your shape tween with the line, and on a separate layer do a motion tween with the tip, using a duplicate of your line as a motion path. you might have to [tweak the points of the shape tween with shape hints](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/animate/using/shape-tweening.html#control_shape_changes_with_shape_hints) but that should solve most of your issues.